# Getting error while launching IDLE from cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, python-idle

I cannot launch IDLE from cygwin for some reason.  When I try to open one of my python files using idle, I do the following:

```
idle file_name.py
```

and I get the following  error:

```
-sh: idle: command not found
```

Any ideas why this is  happening?  For me the same thing happens in git bash, but perhaps it is  the  same problem?

Comment: Do you have the python package installed in Cygwin? (see also http://superuser.com/a/593589/141)

Comment: I do have the packages installed now, thanks for the suggestion.  Idle still refuses to launch and I have a "no display name" error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845812/no-display-name-error-when-launching-idle-in-cygwin)

Comment: @holaSenor What error? idle not found or 'no display'. If it's idle not found then you need to install the idle cygwin package (run cygwin setup); You will also need a running X server (there should be a cygwin package), and set the display variable: `export DISPLAY=:0.0`, in order to get the idle GUI to appear on your desktop.

Comment: Check your `PATH` variable and the location of your IDLE binary.