# "No display name" error when launching idle in cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, python-idle

I am getting a "Tlc error: no display name...etc" when I try to open  python scripts in idle using Cygwin.  I type the  following:

`idle python_script.py`

Do I need to install another Cygwin package to make this work?  Windows 7- recently installed.   Thanks!!:)

Comment: I should mention that idle will launch when I run the idle files using cygstart:  For example, `cygstart idle.bat` will launch idle.

Comment: However, I run `idle` through git bash, and it works just fine.  ??

Comment: I have no experience with cygwin on windows.  Did you compile Python yourself on cygwin?   Is there any reason to not use the PSF windows installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the program cannot find a display to show the window on. To solve that you need to install [X Windows system](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup-cygwin-x-installing.html) and then set the display environment variable to:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9418800/342473